# Position any kind of elements on SVG Curves

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to position elements on along an SVG curve. I found that we can use `textpath` to position text along the `path` of an SVG can we do the same with list-elements? If so how to achieve that functionality

## Html for positioning text along an SVG

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 425 300">
    <path id="curve"
        d="M6,150C49.63,93,105.79,36.65,156.2,47.55,207.89,58.74,213,131.91,264,150c40.67,14.43,108.57-6.91,229-145" />
    <text x="25">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
            This text is now curved
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

## CSS for the same - Just makes it look nice

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
}

path {
  fill: transparent;
}

text {
  fill: #FF9800;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
}

path {
  fill: transparent;
}

text {
  fill: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 425 300">
    <path id="curve"
        d="M6,150C49.63,93,105.79,36.65,156.2,47.55,207.89,58.74,213,131.91,264,150c40.67,14.43,108.57-6.91,229-145" />
    <text x="25">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
            This text is now curved
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Can I achieve this functionality for other elements? list elements for example

**Note: My final objective is to position small circles (filled) along the curve that are equally spaced.**

I'm not very well versed with CSS so if you could point me to resources that will help me achieve this functionality I'll be very grateful

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Why do you mention "list elements" twice?  That normally means text, so your question is troubling me.  Do you want that, or simply just the circles.  Someone asked a very similar question a week or two ago, but appeared to not be happy with the answer they got. Was that you?

Comment: Does "along the curve equaly spaced" mean "spread to fill the length of the curve", or just "at a specified spacing from one another starting at the beginning"? A mockup image would be useful.

Comment: By along the curve equally spaced I meant that the circles should be spread to fill the length of the curve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do what you want with CSS.

You'll need to use some Javascript.  Here's a little example where you can adjust the number of circles, and they will be spaced out evenly along the total length of the path.

```js
let countField = document.getElementById("count");


function updateCircles()
{
   let n = countField.value;
   // Find the curve path element
   let curve = document.getElementById("curve");
   // Get the total length of the path
   let curveLength = curve.getTotalLength();
   // Calculate the spacing between the circles
   let spacing = curveLength / (n - 1);
   
   let svg = curve.ownerSVGElement;
   // Remove any existing circles
   let oldCircles = svg.querySelectorAll("circle");
   oldCircles.forEach(oldCircle => svg.removeChild(oldCircle));
   
   // Add the n new circles
   for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      // Get the x,y position of a point x along the path
      let coords = curve.getPointAtLength(i * spacing);
      // Make a circle
      let circle = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "circle");
      circle.cx.baseVal.value = coords.x;
      circle.cy.baseVal.value = coords.y;
      circle.r.baseVal.value = 6;
      // Append it to the SVG
      svg.appendChild(circle);
   }
}


// Update the circles at the start to show the initial set of circles
updateCircles();
// Update the circles whenever the input changes
countField.addEventListener("input", updateCircles);
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: linen;
}

circle {
  fill: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 160">
    <path id="curve"
        d="M6,150C49.63,93,105.79,36.65,156.2,47.55,207.89,58.74,213,131.91,264,150c40.67,14.43,108.57-6.91,229-145" />
</svg>


<input type="range" id="count" value="4" min="3" max="32"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Note: My final objective is to position small circles (filled) along
> the curve that are equally spaced.

`textPath` is used to place text along a curve. But you can use Unicode characters instead of text characters.

By using textPath and placing unicode characters inside

`<tspan dx =" 5 "fill =" gold "> &#9899; </ tspan>` tags, you can easily place as many circles as you like on one curve.

Here is a [link](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=circle) to the unicode characters of the various circles.

Unicode characters can be styled - `fill =" red "`, resized - `font-size =" 32px "` set the distance between circles `dx =" 10 "`

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="80 100 400 300">
 <path id="pathChain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="skyblue" fill="none"/>
<text font-size="14px" x="0" y="0" font-family="Times New Roman" fill="grey" shape-rendering ="crispEdges" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathChain">
  <tspan dx="0" dy="-2" fill="green" > &#9899; </tspan> <tspan dx="5" dy="-2" fill="gold"> &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="5" fill="crimson"> &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="10" fill="dodgerblue">  &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="0" fill="green" > &#9899; </tspan> <tspan dx="5" fill="gold"> &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="5" fill="crimson"> &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="10" fill="dodgerblue">  &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="0" fill="green" > &#9899; </tspan> <tspan dx="5" fill="gold"> &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="5" fill="crimson"> &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="10" fill="dodgerblue">  &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="0" fill="green" > &#9899; </tspan> <tspan dx="5" fill="gold"> &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="5" fill="crimson"> &#9899;</tspan><tspan dx="10" fill="dodgerblue">  &#9899;</tspan>
  </textPath>
</text>             
</svg>
```

Another example that mimics the chain using unicode characters
Added animation of chain links movement

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="100 100 400 300">
 <path id="pathChain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>
<text font-size="36"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="grey" >
  <textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathChain">
  <tspan dx="0" > &#7441; </tspan> <tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan>
<animate  dur="10s" repeatCount="2" attributeName="startOffset" values="1%;55%;1%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>             
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't place shapes arbitrarily along a path in SVG using just CSS. Your choices here are:

- Don't use a shape, use a text element with tabs and circle characters instead ( e.g. Unicode circle (U+23FA)) and change the font-color to whatever you want
- Use a marker - but placement of these is set to the start, middle & end of each curve segment ([marker tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/marker-element.html))
- Use javascript (e.g. pointAtLength) to calculate the locations of points along a path that you would like to draw circles and set the cx, cy of your circles to those points.